# How to get friends of friends of friends...

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get friends of friends of friends. I get results back but I am not sure if my query is correct. I am using nested select.

My question is:

1. Is the query correct?
2. How can i do this query using join?

This is my friend table

```
rowId  userId  friendId
-----  ------  --------
1      1       4
2      1       2
3      2       10
4      3       6
..     ..      ..
```

This is what i do to get friends:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(friendId) FROM `user_friend`
WHERE userId = $userID
```

This is what I do to get friends of friends

```
SELECT DISTINCT(friendId) FROM `user_friend`
WHERE userId IN (SELECT DISTINCT(friendId) FROM `user_friend`
                WHERE userId = $userID)
```

This is what I do to get friends of friends of friends

```
SELECT DISTINCT(friendId) FROM `user_friend`
WHERE userId IN (SELECT DISTINCT(friendId) FROM `user_friend`
                WHERE userId IN (SELECT DISTINCT(friendId) FROM `user_friend`
                                WHERE userId = $userID))
```

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: And that DISTINCT in these sub-querys make no difference at all to the final result.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly easier using joins...

```
SELECT DISTINCT u3.friendId FROM user_friend u1
   JOIN user_friend u2 ON u1.friendId = u2.userId
   JOIN user_friend u3 ON u2.friendId = u3.userId
   WHERE u1.userId = $userId
```

Comment: This query took about 2 minutes. My Nested query took about 12 seconds. I have got 500000 test data. Is it normal?

Comment: I think the query time result is wrong on phpmyadmin. it says "Query took 2.4342 seconds" but it takes 2 minutes for the records to display. I might try the terminal. I think join is much faster.

Comment: I'm surprised that the JOIN query is taking longer than the nested queries... I'd be interested to know the result on doing it in the terminal... (there is an index on `userId`, right?)

Comment: Ok, Join takes about 4 seconds and nested one takes about 5 or 6  seconds

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be coherent.

The only thing you miss is that you should not return $userId which can be a friend of its friends' friends

EDIT : I don't know if your database already contains friendship in both way. So you also have to consider that if A is friend of B then B is friend of A and test for it.

So you have to play with a possible inversion in t2 like in the following

```
 SELECT t1.userId FROM user_friend t1
     JOIN user_friend t2 ON t1.friendId=t2.userId
     JOIN user_friend t3 ON t2.friendId=t3.userId
     WHERE t3.friendId=$userId AND t1.userId!=$userId
UNION
  SELECT t1.userId FROM user_friend t1
     JOIN user_friend t2 ON t1.friendId=t2.friendId
     JOIN user_friend t3 ON t2.userId=t3.userId
     WHERE t3.friendId=$userId AND t1.userId!=$userId;
```

Also, this includes friends of friends of friends, but not friends of friends.

Comment: That's a good point, I imagine that there could be all sorts of loops in there like you are a friend of a friend and your friend is a friend of a friend of a friend, depending on how the table is structured I suppose...

Comment: And probably have to consider if you want to include (or not) those who are only friends of friends.

Comment: This query took about 2 minutes. My Nested query took about 12 seconds. I have got 500000 test data. Is it normal?

Comment: I think the query time result is wrong on phpmyadmin. it says "Query took 2.4342 seconds" but it takes 2 minutes for the records to display. I might try the terminal. I think join is much faster.