# Friends of Friends query for 1 way relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table: (friends)

| user_id | friend_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 8 |
| 11 | 7 |

The table contains 1 way relationship. For eg. User 1 is following User 3, but User 3 is not following User 1.

So Each user has Followers and Following data.

What I want in my output is:

Get **Followers** of selected user + followers and following of those **Followers**

Plus (+)

Get **Followings** of selected user + followers and following of those **Followings**

***Desired Output:-***

| user_id | friend_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 |

This is my current query:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
  FROM friends t1
  JOIN friends t2 ON t1.friend_id=t2.user_id
 WHERE t2.friend_id=$user_id
 UNION
SELECT t1.*
  FROM friends t1
  JOIN friends t2 ON t1.friend_id=t2.friend_id
 WHERE t2.friend_id=$user_id
;
```

I got this query from here: [How to get friends of friends of friends...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692331/how-to-get-friends-of-friends-of-friends) (@Adams answer)

But I don't think it is looping through all the condition that I want in my case. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Edit:- @sajjad rezaei answer satisfies all the conditions, but is not exactly the output that I wanted.
(my bad, I should have added my desired output.)

Here is the dbfiddle link of the output:- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sWVYZKVWMbbEUkShJmje2Q/5

Comment: Create the test case containing your data.  Post the detail, and maybe a link to the fiddle (dbfiddle.uk).  What result did you get?  What result did you expect?

Comment: Hey @JonArmstrong sorry for late reply, I have added a fiddle link with sajjad's query, which does satisfies my conditions, but it is not in the desired output format that I want. (I edited his query a bit and replaced "f1.*" with "user_id" and "friend_id".)

Comment: Are you really using MySQL 5.7?

Comment: dbfiddle was by default set to 5.7, but because of you pointing it out, I checked MySQL version in my Laragon project. Turns out Laragon installs MySQL 5.7.33 by default, thankfully its really easy to upgrade to version 8 of MySQL, I will be doing this soon! Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Check out the answer with the recursive `<with clause>`, available in MySQL 8.0+.  This provides the ability to query any level of friend depth with the same form.  Adjust the `AND n < 3` term as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34712e9127dc140dccd3f1e54fdcbc58)

Here's one for MySQL 5.7 (8.0 or less):

```sql
SELECT user_id, friend_id
  FROM (
         SELECT f.user_id, f.friend_id   FROM friends AS f WHERE 1 IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id) UNION
         SELECT f.user_id, f.friend_id
           FROM (
                   SELECT f.user_id, f.friend_id   FROM friends AS f WHERE 1 IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id)
                ) AS f0
           JOIN friends AS f
             ON f0.user_id   IN (f.friend_id, f.user_id)
             OR f0.friend_id IN (f.friend_id, f.user_id)
                
     ) AS fof
 ORDER BY user_id, friend_id
;
```

Here's one for MySQL 8.0+:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE fof (user_id, friend_id, n) AS (
         SELECT f.user_id, f.friend_id, 1   FROM friends AS f WHERE 1 IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id) UNION ALL  
         SELECT f.user_id, f.friend_id, n+1
           FROM friends AS f
           JOIN fof     AS f2
             ON (  f.user_id   IN (f2.friend_id, f2.user_id)
                OR f.friend_id IN (f2.friend_id, f2.user_id)
                )
            AND n < 2
     )
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, friend_id
  FROM fof
 ORDER BY user_id, friend_id
;
```

The result:

| user_id | friend_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 |

I used the following to count the larger data set...

Non-recursive:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (
         SELECT f.user_id, f.friend_id   FROM friends AS f WHERE 1066 IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id) UNION
         SELECT f.user_id, f.friend_id
           FROM (
                   SELECT f.user_id, f.friend_id   FROM friends AS f WHERE 1066 IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id)
                ) AS f0
           JOIN friends AS f
             ON f0.user_id   IN (f.friend_id, f.user_id)
             OR f0.friend_id IN (f.friend_id, f.user_id)
     ) AS fof
;
```

Recursive:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE fof (user_id, friend_id, n) AS (
         SELECT f.user_id, f.friend_id, 1   FROM friends AS f WHERE 1066 IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id) UNION ALL  
         SELECT f.user_id, f.friend_id, n+1
           FROM friends AS f
           JOIN fof     AS f2
             ON (  f.user_id   IN (f2.friend_id, f2.user_id)
                OR f.friend_id IN (f2.friend_id, f2.user_id)
                )
            AND n < 2
     )
   , xxx AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT user_id, friend_id
          FROM fof
         ORDER BY user_id, friend_id
     )
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx
;
```

The result:

```
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    12125 |
+----------+
```

Comment: I ran your First query (v5.7) and @forpas query on my bigger test table (13030 rows) which was scrapped from a Instagram user, who has id 1066 in this test table. Ideally my output should have 13030 rows as answer, cause the test table only has data of user 1066's followers and following and their followers and following. Your query returns 11,681 rows, while his query returns 12,125 rows, but your query (0.18s) was 2x faster than his(0.4). I think I might have missed some conditions in my demo table that I have provided.

Comment: @Sniper1999 Try to find a minimal test case (with data) that shows the issue.  The logic of the above query removes duplicates.  Maybe you're not accounting for duplicates.

Comment: Yes, right now checking for duplicates in my original test table. Ill return to you as soon as I find out whats causing this issue.

Comment: @Sniper1999 There may be no literal duplicate `(user, friend)` pairs, but some specific pairs may be found/visited more than once in the (friend graph) logic you're using. I've added a few more cases to the data and see no issue so far.  All queries produce the same result.  I would recheck your 13030 calculation.  I suspect that might be the problem.  Feel free to post that data somewhere.

Comment: My test table indeed had 904 duplicated rows, which leaves me with 12,125 unique rows in total. @forpas query does seem to return right number of rows. Here is the test table in csv: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Z1smMKFgnDCjt4ZDBH11DvRcMWAYlWb/view?usp=sharing and in .sql: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yy6KAVN9Ezo_UOg-eyNaYXRCy9PX_CrK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Humm, so your second query (v8.0) returns only 1810 rows. I don't know what exactly is wrong in this query. For now, I will mark @forpas query as the right answer, although his query is a bit slow compared to yours. His query might not be ideal for very large no. of rows, but then if I had used Graph DB this would not have been a problem.

Comment: @Sniper1999 Check that you're using the right starting user_id.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to edit the value for user_id, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: hey @Jon Armstrong sorry for late reply. For now I am using forpas's query in my project. I will look into your answer in detail when I have time. Again, thank you very much for your assistance in my problem. I will get back to you, once I understand your query properly.

Comment: @Sniper1999 I've corrected the logic.

Answer (score 2):

With this query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN user_id = 1 THEN friend_id ELSE user_id END id
FROM friends
WHERE 1 IN (user_id, friend_id);
```

you get all the followers and followings of user = 1.

Join it to the table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.user_id, f.friend_id
FROM friends f 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT CASE WHEN user_id = 1 THEN friend_id ELSE user_id END id
  FROM friends
  WHERE 1 IN (user_id, friend_id)
) t ON t.id IN (f.user_id, f.friend_id)
ORDER BY f.user_id, f.friend_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38cbbaf60a25084188129cd86a4ad090).

Comment: Thank your @forpas for providing this query, it works as expected for my purpose.

Comment: @Sniper1999 is there any reason that you unaccepted my answer? In any test with your sample data it performs better: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sSqkN1wce15sx7wQL5dw1D/0 vs https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iFxQc8g97vDwKwjE7JycSm/0

Answer (score 1):

It might help you with your situation:

```
(SELECT f1.* , 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(friend_id) from friends WHERE user_id = f1.friend_id) AS followerOFfollowers,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) from friends WHERE friend_id = f1.friend_id) AS followingOFfollowers
FROM friends as f1
WHERE f1.user_id = 1 GROUP by f1.id , f1.friend_id)

UNION

(SELECT f1.* , 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(friend_id) from friends WHERE user_id = f1.user_id) AS followerOFfollowers,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) from friends WHERE friend_id = f1.user_id) AS followingOFfollowers
FROM friends as f1
WHERE f1.friend_id = 1 GROUP by f1.id , f1.user_id)
```

Comment: Hey @sajjad rezaei thank you for this solution, it does satisfy all my conditions. But it is not in the exact output format that I want it to be. I have edited the original question and added my desired output table and added the dbfiddle link. Can you help me with this? Thanks again, and sorry for the late reply.